# Firebase: Mixing version can lead to runtime crashes

Tags: android, firebase

I am using Android Studio 3.1.3 and try to build an Android App connected to Firebase.

I have the following error in the `build.gradle` file.

[image]

My `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.asu.fit.firebaseapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Would you please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: To add to @Reaz Murshed's answer if you wish to track down the versions for dependencies run `./gradlew app:dependencies`. It will list down all your dependencies with version, which may help in debugging your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly says that you are having different versions of a support library which might lead to runtime crashes. In this case, you might consider doing the following.

1. You can lower the `targetSdkVersion` to **26** and change the import of support library version to `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'`. Then try syncing again using gradle.
2. Or you might use `resolutionStrategy` to force the library version to be used while building your application like the following. Add the following segment in your `build.gradle` file.

   ```
   configurations.all {
       resolutionStrategy {
           force 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
           force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
           force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
       }
   }
   ```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

After that i hope i will work well.